# OCaml functional update with nested record

Tags: ocaml

Is there a way, possibly using a ppx extension or similar, to use the functional update syntax `{ record with key = value }` with a nested record?

For instance, in the following example program I'm functionally updating only the outermost record, when I really want to target an "inner" one.

```
type outer = {
  a : float;
  b : inner
}
and inner = {
  c : float;
}

let item = { a = 0.4; b = { c = 0.7 } }

let () = ignore { item with b = { c = 0.8 }
```

It becomes less convenient if `inner` has more than one field.

I'd like to be able to write something like the following (strawman syntax):

```
let () = ignore { item with b.c = 0.8 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this in straight OCaml:

```
{ item with b = { item.b with c = 0.8 } }
```

I assume you're using `ignore` just for the examples; it doesn't make sense to ignore the result of a functional record update.

Comment: It seems like, in a certain sense, the answer is "no" then. It sounds like `key` in `{record with key = value}` can only be a single field and there aren't any commonly used extensions out there that would allow more kinds of things in the `key`-position ... and possibly desugar into multiple functional updates like this.

Comment: Yes, the grammar of straight OCaml calls for a *field* after `with`. This is a single identifier possibly preceded by the names of containing modules (where the record type is defined).